# While Read and AWK to Change Field

Tags: awk, while-loop

I have two files - FileA and FileB.  **FileA** has 10 fields with 100 lines.  If Field1 and Field2 match, Field3 should be changed.  **FileB** has 3 fields.  I am reading in FileB with a while loop to match the two fields and to get the value that should be use for field 3.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read hostname interface metric; do
 awk -v var1=${hostname} -v var2=${interface} -v var3=${metric}  '{if ($1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2) $3=var3; print $0}' OFS="\t" FileA.txt
done < FileB.txt
```

At each line iteration, this prints FileB.txt with the single line that changed.  I only want it to print the line that was changed.

Please Help!

Comment: Some sample data would be good: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your approach is unnecessarily complicated, fragile, and slow. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and [@GlennJackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45984794/1745001). In addition to the looping problems, `${hostname}` is no different than `$hostname` when what you REALLY need is `"$hostname"` - always quote your shell variables.

Answer (score 2):

It's a smell to be calling awk once for each line of file B. You should be able to accomplish this task with a single pass through each file.

Try something like this:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    # first, read in data from file B
    NR == FNR { values[$1 FS $2] = $3; next }

    # then, output modified lines from matching lines in file A
    ($1 FS $2) in values { $3 = values[$1 FS $2]; print }
' fileB fileA
```

I'm assuming that you actually want to match with string equality instead of `~` pattern matching.

Comment: Glenn, this works and seems more efficient.  Can you tell me though how I can print a line that does match and ALSO lines that don't?

Comment: like this: `($1 FS $2) in values { $3 = values[$1 FS $2] } {print}` -- putting the print statement into its own block with no condition means that every line gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want it to print the line that was changed.

Simply put your `print $0` statement to `if` clause body:

```
'{if ($1 ~ var1 && $2 ~ var2) { $3=var3; print $0 }}'
```

or even shorter:

```
'$1~var1 && $2~var2{ $3=var3; print $0 }'
```

Comment: @user3746195, even more shorter `'$1~var1 && $2~var2{ $3=var3 }1'`